# Using supertest to check didFlash after a redirect

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, compoundjs, supertest

I'm trying to test what happens when the user destroy callback receives an error for the user controller. When destroy receives an error, it does the following:

```
flash('error', 'Can not destroy user');
redirect(path_to.users);
```

This is the test so far:

```
it('should fail on DELETE /users/:id if destroy receives an error', function (done) {
    var User = app.models.User;
    var user = new UserStub();

    User.find = sinon.spy(function (id, callback) {
        callback(null, user);
    });

    user.destroy = sinon.spy(function (callback) {
        callback(new Error());
    });

    request(app)
        .del('/users/55')
        .end(function (err, res) {
            res.header.location.should.include('/users');
            app.didFlash('error').should.be.true;

            done();
        });
});
```

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272228/testing-requests-that-redirect-with-mocha-supertest-in-node) and the `res.header..` portion works as expected. However, I'm still confused on how I can test the flash that happens after that redirect.

Comment: I'm not sure how to test the flash on a redirect yet, but `app.didFlash` will detect a flash on a render. Since your redirect is in the same controller, you could render the index instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the users_controller to use the following code for a destroy callback (the redirect was having other issues):

```
if (error) {
    flash('error', 'Can not destroy user');
} else {
    flash('info', 'User successfully removed');
}
send(302, "'" + pathTo.users + "'");
```

The init.js file used with mocha.js has a few pieces in it when initializing the app object (some irrelevant code was omitted):

```
global.getApp = function(done) {
    var app = require('compound').createServer();

    app.renderedViews = [];
    app.flashedMessages = {};

    app._render = app.render;
    app.render = function (viewName, opts, fn) {
        app.renderedViews.push(viewName);

        // Deep-copy flash messages
        var flashes = opts.request.session.flash;
        for(var type in flashes) {
            app.flashedMessages[type] = [];
            for(var i in flashes[type]) {
                app.flashedMessages[type].push(flashes[type][i]);
            }
        }

        return app._render.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        app._request = req;
        next();
    });

    app.didFlash = function (type) {
        var flashes = app._request.session.flash;        
        return !!(app.flashedMessages[type] || (flashes && flashes[type]));

    };

    return app;
};
```

The [original way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555703/how-to-setup-mocha-tests-with-node-js-and-passport) of checking for `didFlash` was limited to only rendering, but this checks if a flash message is created before a `redirect` or `send`.